# Complicated scope involving multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to create a scope that would provide me with all `clients` that made a `purchase` after they've `:transitioned_to_maintenance` (a term we use internally).

My models and scopes are organized as follows:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :program_transitions
    has_many :purchases

    scope :transitioned_to_maintenance, -> { where(id: ProgramTransition.to_maintenance.pluck(:client_id)) }
    scope :has_purchases, -> { where(id: Purchase.pluck(:client_id)) }
end

class ProgramTransition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, required: true

  scope :to_fm, -> { where(new_status: "full maintenance") }
  scope :to_lm, -> { where(new_status: "limited maintenance") }
  scope :to_maintenance, -> { to_fm.or(to_lm)}
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end
```

I could accomplish what I am trying to do by looping through the clients and selected those that meet my criteria, but I was hoping it'd be possible through a scope.  Here it is as a model level function:

```
def self.purchased_after_maintenance
    clients = Client.transitioned_to_maintenance.has_purchases
    final = []

    clients.each do |client|
        min_date = client.program_transitions.to_maintenance.first.created_at
        final << client if client.purchases.last.created_at >= ? min_date
    end
end
```

**Is this possible to do with a scope and without looping through all clients?**

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things before addressing the main question. Don't mean to be annoying and not address the main question first, but I thought this could be helpful.

1. Instead of `scope :transitioned_to_maintenance, -> { where(id: ProgramTransition.to_maintenance.pluck(:client_id)) }`, I would do this (see below). [merge](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) is really powerful and something we have been using a lot lately at our company.

```
scope :transitioned_to_maintenance, -> { joins(:program_transitions).merge(ProgramTransition.to_maintenance) }
```

2. Instead of doing `scope :has_purchases, -> { where(id: Purchase.pluck(:client_id)) }`, I would just do `scope :has_purchases, -> { joins(:purchases) }`, as the joins on purchases will only return clients that have associated purchases.

Regarding the main question, I can't think of a good way to do this with scopes, but it's probably possible. If I were you I would ask your data team what the SQL would look like for that query, and then try to figure out the active record needed to create it. However, if you stick with your way, here is a slight refactor I would recommend. Using `select` instead of `each` and eager loading to avoid n+1 queries.

```
def self.purchased_after_maintenance
  Client.joins(:purchases, :program_transitions).includes(:purchases, :program_transitions).transitioned_to_maintenance.select do |client|
    transition_date = client.program_transitions.to_maintenance.first.created_at
    client.purchases.last.created_at >= transition_date 
  end
end
```

Hope this helps, and sorry I don't have the answer with the scopes.